# WndProc method(windows messaging) not getting data while mimimize my application

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application, messaging

I am overriding method WndProc in C# for getting data ,sent from VB.net application. I am receiving data properly but problem is when I minimize my application I am not able to receive data, when again i maximize application it works fine. (issue like threading pause/start)

I have searched some solutions.Some says set property 'ShowInTaskbar=false'. 
Some says problem of Handler that Handle not created.

But I didn't find better solution.

Do you have any idea to short out this problem.

following is my C# Code :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
switch (m.Msg)
{
    case 0x401:
        if(x==0)
            BuildString.ReceivedString(m.LParam);
        break;

    default:
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: HI,mins, link that you 've provided says that close the application while minimize application or avoid minimize. but it is not the solution.

Comment: Using SendMessage() is an exceedingly brittle way to implement process interop.  Biggest problem is that you just have no good way to find out that it failed to get the job done.  Especially risky in Winforms, ShowInTaskbar is not the only property that causes the Handle property to change.  You can debug it by overriding OnHandleCreated() and setting a breakpoint on it.  Don't do this at all, use a socket, named pipe or WCF instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I have client driver application already built in VB.net and provided mechanism to send data continues. I am developing C# application that takes those data and render it to my application .So forcefully i have to use this concept. do you have any solutions regarding this please let me know. and thanks for comment.

Comment: I gave you a debugging tip, I recommend you use it to eliminate a possible failure mode.  If you don't post an MCVE then you'll need to find a site where psychics hand out free advice.